# gtest typed test filtering issues

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have a big set of unit and some integration tests implemented with google test framework or gtest.

Since there is no tagging I am using the disable convention to separate tests in groups or prefixing them with `GROUPA_`, `GROUPB_`, etc.

This works well. I can filter different groups, to run in different situations etc.

The problem I have is with typed tests that belong to different groups. Since the name of the test is fixed no matter what arguments I pass to the test fixture I cannot assign the same test to more than one group.

My question is, can I control the name of the test somehow runtime before the runner or something. Any other way to control the name of a typed tests?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can include a typed test into the different groups but for all the types. You could use as many prefixes as needed:

```
TYPED_TEST(FooTest, GROUPA_GROUPB_Bar)
{
}
```

Then use filtering strings like `FooTest.*GROUPX*_Bar`.

I cannot think of a way to map each type the test is instanciated for to a a different group.

Comment: Yeap, but this will put all the tests in all groups. It is something ... but not what I need.